# Update ViewHolder Without Re-Populating RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to populate views dynamically as data is added to Firebase.

However, I also want to modify the views that the `RecyclerView` populates as data changes in `Firebase`. For instance, I have a counter on each view that is populated, and as people vote on that topic, I want the counter to increase:

My idea is to set a tag to each view that is populated in the `RecyclerView`, find a way to get the current views that are on the screen, and then update those views dynamically. I am kind of lost how I would proceed, but here is my PollHolder:

```
    public static class PollHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mPollQuestion;
    TextView mVoteCount;
    ImageView mPollImage;
    View mView;
    String mTag;


    public PollHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mPollQuestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.latest_item_question);
        mPollImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pollThumbNailImage);
        mVoteCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.latest_item_poll_count);
        this.mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setVoteCount (String voteCount){
        mVoteCount.setText(voteCount);
    }

    public void setTag(String tag){
        this.mTag = tag;
    }

    public View getViewByTag(String tag){
        return mView;
    }

}
```

Here are the views in the `RecyclerView`. I want the counter in the lower right corner to update, but again I do not want to completely recreate/repopulate the `RecyclerView`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you insert new  get the position of that row.Then you can refresh specific row by using

```
notifyItemInserted (int position);
```

Its not refresh or recreate all data in  RecyclerView but its alternate the count of list and refresh the particular position.

Representations of other existing items in the data set are still considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their positions may be altered.

More details refer [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: I think you're talking about notifyItemChanged, not notifyItemInserted.